# Why does Pandas chose different colors for hist?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert a dataframe into all numeric and draw a histogram, but the hist hast two colors and if I try to set the color, it says that two datasets were provided.

> ValueError: The 'color' keyword argument must have one color per dataset, but 2 datasets and 1 colors were provided

```
#Get df_num
df_num = df_encoded.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64'])

#Get histogram of distribution
df_num.hist(figsize=(16, 20), bins=10, xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=8, color='r')
```

How did I get two dataset by calling `.hist()` on one dataframe?

I have tried to set the color to one color.

Comment: Your question is missing reproducible data to know what 's going on.  Maybe you can add the output of `df_num.head()` in text format to your post? If you get two histograms, you probably have two columns in that dataframe.